# MVC4 Package Installation Error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, installation, asp.net-mvc-4

I installed MVC4 side-by-side with MVC3.

When I create a new MVC4 web app project in VS 2010, I get this error:

[image: mvc4 error]

There is nothing about that on Google.

Any idea ?

Comment: Are you installing through NuGet? If so it might be worth checking NuGet is up to date and that you have SP1 on VS2010 as that's required for MVC4. If all else fails you can download an installer from the asp.net website

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you to [AndyM](https://stackoverflow.com/users/208908/andym) for the help.

Here's how I solved the issue:

**1.** Uninstall NuGet in Windows Add/Remove Programs

**2.** Opening the following folder `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft Corporation\NuGet Package Manager`

**3.** Delete all folders and files there

**4.** Uninstall MVC 4 in Windows Add/Remove Programs then reinstall MVC 4

Comment: Thanks, this helped me.  For future readers, I was able to fix the same issue by simply updating NuGet Package Manager in Extension Manager.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use extension manager from tools menu in Visual Studio 2010, uninstall and then install nuget and works fine.